# Change Text color of checked item in Listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I am populating a `ListView` from a file. The `ListvVew`contains checkboxes. Now I want to **change the color and font of the text of individual items on checkbox click**. Instead I am only able to highlight the individual item row (to blue). What am I missing?

**main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#F3E2A9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutlist"
       android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"

        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listviewcolor"

        >
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**listviewcolor.xml**

```
    <!-- Selected -->
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/blue" />

  <!-- Default -->
  <item android:drawable="@color/lightyellow" />
```

**color.xml**

```
<color name="blue">#ff3a8dcb</color>    
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="lightyellow">#F3E2A9</color>
```

**main_activity**

```
    List arrlist=new ArrayList();  
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1, arrlist);  //arrlist is an ArrayList
                                                                                                                         //whose value is taken from a file
    listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
        listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change `TextColor` and `TextFont` Size programmatically on `Checkbox` `onCheckedChangeListener()`

```
 tx.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,30);
 tx.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: I am not using `checkboxes`. See my layout. `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` makes the item checkable in the `listview`

Answer (score 1):

Please show your list item layout where you added check box and text view and in your adapter change text colour and font dynamically on Checkbox onCheckedChangeListener() like as follows :

```
   final Typeface tvFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "OPTIMA.TTF");
    tv.setTypeface(tvFont);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: No `checkboxes` and `textview` were added. The `listview` on `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` makes the checkboxes. The `listview` layout is already given

Comment: please use custom row list item its easy to handle all dynamic operations like colour change and font change of textview